# How to receive a num at each step and continue until zero is entered; then this program should print the sum of enter nums

Tags: python

How to Write a program that receive a number from the input at each step and continue to work until zero is entered.  After the zero digit is entered, this program should print the sum of the entered numbers. I want to get n different numbers in n different lines and it stops when it reaches Zero

**For ex:(input:)**

> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 0

**Output:**

> 12

Actually I have this code but it doesn’t work:
‘’’python’’’

```
Sum= 0

Num = int(input())

While num!=0 :

   Num = int(input())

   Sum+= num

Print(sum)
```

**But it gives ‘9’ instead of ‘12’**

Comment: Can you give an example of your current code?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Try to give us a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we know what you have done and where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code:-**

```
total_sum=0
n=int(input("Enter the number: "))
while n!=0:
    total_sum+=n
    n=int(input("Enter the number: "))
print("The total sum until the user input 0 is: "+str(total_sum))
```

**Output:-**

**#Testcase1** user_input:- 10, 0

```
Enter the number: 10
Enter the number: 0
The total sum until the user input 0 is: 10
```

**#Testcase2** user_input:- 3, 4, 5, 0

```
Enter the number: 3
Enter the number: 4
Enter the number: 5
Enter the number: 0
The total sum until the user input 0 is: 12
```

**#Improvisation** - { **Removing the redundancy of n initialization in above code** (which is two times before the while loop and inside the while loop)}

**Code:-**

```
total_sum=0
while True:
    n=int(input("Enter the number: "))
    total_sum+=n
    if not n:
        break
print("The total sum until the user input 0 is: "+str(total_sum))
```

**Output:-**

**Same as above**

Comment:  it did work; can you pls explain why when I write the 3d and 4th lines in a different way it the wrong output is printed?!( 9 instead of 12)

Comment: As i debug your code what happens in your code is when you enter the number 3 it is not added in total_sum than you enter next number it stored in total sum.. so point is the 1st value is not adding in your total sum. you updating

Comment: if you change the 3rd and 4th line than first number you enter will be added to total sum than you asking for next number..! I think you got the point..

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm using a while loop that continues until the user input is 0 then prints out the sum.

```
res = 0
user_input = int(input('Input a number: '))
while user_input != 0:
    res+= user_input
    user_input=int(input('Input a number: '))

print("You entered 0 so the program stopped. The sum of your inputs is: {}".format(res))
```

Comment: Thx but when I have these numbers:3, 4, 5 , 0. It doesn’t work and gives 9 instead of 12.or when I have 10, 0 in the input it gives zero in the output instead of 10

Comment: In your code.. The 1st value user input is not added to the result..

Comment: s0rry I fixed it